# Can I Track Pop-Up Displays Using Google Analytics Event Tracking

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I'm trying track the number of times a pop-up displays on my site, but can't get it to show as an Event in Google Analytics.
I've included this in the pop-up itself:

```
    <a href="http://www.domain.com/destination"><img src="http://www.domain.com/popup.jpg" onload=”ga(‘send’, ‘event’, ‘popups’, ‘popup1’);“></a>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm closing this question because the problem was due to a typo with your code.   You found the problem and corrected it, but this question is unlikely to be helpful to future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I found the problem. The single and double quote marks were improperly formatted. (You can see they're the slanted versions, when I should have used the vertical ones.)

Comment: The good old "smart" quotes vs. "straight" quotes issues. Gets them every time!